# Program ignoring code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

```
Private Sub Play_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Play.Click    
    WordGeneration()                                                           
    userInput()
```

Once the user has clicked a button which has been implemented into my form it will  then run each sub specified . However the problem is , i do not want the sub WordGeneration() being run more than once . Is there a way for me to program into my code to stop WordGeneration() from being run more than once so it doesnt keep randomly generating a word , as i only want it to generate one word.

Comment: Use a Boolean variable which once WordGeneration() has been called is set to true then wrap inside an `If Not variable Then WordGeneration End If`

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean sadly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `Boolean` variable which you can set to **True** once you have called the code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _codeCalled As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Play_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Play.Click
        If Not _codeCalled Then    
            WordGeneration()                                           
        End If                
        userInput()  
    End Sub

End Class
```

So in your `WordGeneration` method set the variable `_codeCalled = True`.

This should then only call the method once. Anytime you want to call the method again look at setting `_codeCalled = False`. You may also want to give it a different name which better fits your structure.